# Why did they introduce girls in bikinis in court?

Tags: plot-explanation, spring-breakers

In Spring Breakers (2012), I know this movie contains a lot of women in bikinis & nudity.

But I was shocked to see girls in bikinis even in court. It looks like the judge's decision will be disturbed when he see girls in bikinis.

[image]

Why can't they even provide proper uniforms for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real life, cops are #####, and won't be bothered to provide people anything. One recent instance had a judge go off on the prosecution and police for denying a woman pants when she was put in jail.

In this specific instance, the girls happen to be in a resort town, and given a same day adjournment. They weren't put in jail, just in holding. No time or need to change.

As for the judge, they are expected to remain professional, and in a resort town like that, would see the same thing day after day. In and out of court. It's nothing shocking or special. It would depend on the judge to require a dress code, and in many high volume courts it's very lenient.